# Different mapper classes for each persistent class to save and load objects?

Tags: java, uml

[image]

In the book I read, it is said that for each persistent class, an associated mapper class is defined with the responsibility for storing objects in the database, and for recreating objects based on the stored data values, when requested. People do like that really? If I have two classes which data need to be stored in the database, do I really need to use two seperate classes to read or write from or to database? I have never found such programs. Persistent table is used for what? Can you please give me examples?

Comment: Not necessarily. In practice, all frameworks have their own way to deal with this. For example with JPA, you can define beans that are automatically mapped/unmapped (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671224&seqNum=2).

Comment: You need to understand the ideas you're reading.
Technically you can write a code not following any rules and it might work. The idea behind using methodologies, programming paradigms, frameworks and best practices is to create maintainable code that you will be able to debug, modify, (partially) replace or reuse.
Note that there are many different methodologies and you need to decide which of the methodologies you're going to use. Yet remember - best practices are there to help you even if you don't see now how it helps. Using it will benefit in future.

Comment: Believe it or not, I understand that it is for better matainability when I read that. But I have found no programs follows that practice. (one seperate mapper class for one class) That is why I suspect  my understanding. I am weak in programming. I am also weak in English. There are many things I do not know. I have to read many things to understand one sentence. So even when I understand a little, I can not believe in my understanding. But please do not think that I am not trying. Different person has different conditions. It is not because of my fault.

Answer (score 0):

### No.

The base operations on the persistence class instance are Create, Read,  Update, Delete. And all of them must be able to work with the **same** object of the **same** class, and most probably, the **same** table.

You could make these methods so that you'll read and write to different **tables**. But that all will still be done with the **same** class.